# Only the first polygon is showing up in Leaflet 2.0.1 choropleth plot

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, choropleth, r-sf

My leaflet choropleth plot in my Shiny App is only showing the first polygon after the recent package update to Leaflet 2.0.1.

I had adapted the code from the [Leaflet for R](http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/choropleths.html) webpage and it used to work.

Here is a MRE:

```
library(sf)
library(leaflet)

From http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/us-states.js

states <- read_sf("~/Downloads/cb_2017_us_state_20m/cb_2017_us_state_20m.shp")

leaflet(states) %>%
  setView(-96, 37.8, 2) %>%
  addPolygons(color = "#444444", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,
              opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.5,
              fillColor = ~colorQuantile("YlOrRd", ALAND)(ALAND),
              highlightOptions = 
    highlightOptions(color = "white", 
                     weight = 2, bringToFront = TRUE, dashArray = ""))
```

The output with only the first polygon showing up:

[image: Leaflet plot with only the first polygon showing up]

I have checked the dataset and shapefile, and it looks correct, and can be successfully plotted using the `plot` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, which was to assign `dashArray = NULL`. In the [Leaflet for R](http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/choropleths.html) webpage, the code had `dashArray = ""`. Assigning an empty string to `dashArray` used to work as a default, but now it causes leaflet to only plot the first polygon.

```
library(sf)
library(leaflet)

From http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/us-states.js

states <- read_sf("~/Downloads/cb_2017_us_state_20m/cb_2017_us_state_20m.shp")

leaflet(states) %>%
  setView(-96, 37.8, 2) %>%
  addPolygons(color = "#444444", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,
          opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.5,
          fillColor = ~colorQuantile("YlOrRd", ALAND)(ALAND),
          highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "white", weight = 2,
                                              bringToFront = TRUE,
                                              dashArray = NULL
                                              ))
```

This outputs the correct plot:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug with `leaflet` v 2.x.x

If you remove the `dashArray = ""` command it should render fine i.e.,

```
states <- read_sf("~/Downloads/cb_2017_us_state_20m/cb_2017_us_state_20m.shp")

leaflet(states) %>%
  setView(-96, 37.8, 2) %>%
  addPolygons(color = "#444444", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,
              opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.5,
              fillColor = ~colorQuantile("YlOrRd", ALAND)(ALAND),
              highlightOptions = 
    highlightOptions(color = "white", 
                     weight = 2, bringToFront = TRUE))
```